# Busqueda por similitud en mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo una duda sobre como hacer una busqueda en mongodb

por ejemplo, tengo dos documentos con una propiedad "name" algo asi
{"name": "Desarrolladores de aplicaciones mobiles"}
{"name": "Desarrolladores de aplicaciones web"}

si yo busco "desarrolladres" (notese que omiti la ultima "o"), no me traeria ningun resultado, hay laguna forma de buscar por similitud de palabra?

Answer (score 1):

Sí la hay, en mongo se pueden utilizar expresiones regulares para realizar búsquedas. Por ejemplo, si quieres buscar cualquier documento que contenga la palabra "desarrolladores" (cuidado con las mayúsculas y minúsculas) en cualquier parte del nombre, la búsqueda tendría esta forma:

```
db.documentos.find({"name": /desarrolladores/})
```

Si, por el contrario, solo quieres buscar que el nombre empiece por "Desarrolladores", puedes hacer:

```
db.documentos.find({"name": /^Desarrolladores/})
```

Si quieres que acabe en "desarrolladores, sería:

```
db.documentos.find({"name": /desarrolladores$/})
```

Para que sea insensible a mayúsculas o minúsculas, simplemente añade el flag  'i' después de la expresión regular:

```
db.documentos.find({"name": /desarrolladores/i})
```

Comment: gracias, si se que hay expresiones regulares, pero en mi caso no me sirve, ya que lo que quiero es que sea una busqueda por similitud, o no se como llamarlo, por ejemplo, algo mas claro de lo que ocupo seria algo asi.

si yo busco "desarroyadores", en este caso no me traeria nada, ya que "desarroyadores" no esta incluida en "desarrolladores"

Comment: En resumen, lo que necesito es que encuentre resultados aunque las palabras esten un poco mal escritas, otro ejemplo, tengo un registro que dice "productos enlatados" y yo busco "produts enlatads" encuentre un parecido y me devuelva "productos enlatados", algo similar como funciona el buscador de youtube

Comment: Si necesitas ese tipo de búsqueda avanzado, te sugiero que le eches un vistazo a [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) y a su edge-ngram tokenizer. De esta forma, si escribes mal una palabra, el motor de ElasticSearch te sigue devolviendo resultados.